# Web sharing : Images won't load - 403 Forbidden

Tags: macos, webserver

I've recently "activated" the web sharing in OSX 1.8 « Mountain Lion ». It works well with PHP & HTML. But I stuck with 403 errors with images (jpg, png).

Do you have any idea why ?

Thx

Comment: Are the images in the same directory as the (working) HTML files?

Comment: Yes, of course. If not i'd get a 404 not a 403.

Comment: Not necessarily, but anyway... Can you check the file permissions on the images you are trying to serve?

Comment: Just did before reading your comment. I don't know why, only the owner had read rights. Now it works well. Thx anyway for your help!

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself then with your findings. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in the comments above, the problem was that only the owner of the file did have the rights to read the file.

A simple chmod +r on the file solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at /var/log/apache2/error_log and try to identify your problem. I had :

[Fri Aug 31 13:31:20 2012] [error] [client ::1] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/myname/Sites/

in my /etc/apache2/users/myname.conf i've replace

Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

by

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

That just add FollowSymLinks in Options.

and it was great for me ...